# SqlDependency not firing

Tags: sql, asp.net, webforms, sqldependency

I am trying SqlDepenedency for the first time. I am not getting any notifications on Database Update.

I am placing breakpoints inside :
 `OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)`,

but it never gets hit.

Here is my code :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Text = "Cache Refresh: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        // Create a dependency connection to the database.
        SqlDependency.Start(GetConnectionString());

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(GetSQL(), connection))
            {

                SqlDependency dependency =
                        new SqlDependency(command);

                    // Refresh the cache after the number of minutes
                    // listed below if a change does not occur.
                    // This value could be stored in a configuration file.
                                  connection.Open();

                dgHomeRequests.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dgHomeRequests.DataBind();

            }
        }   
    }


    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        // To avoid storing the connection string in your code,
        // you can retrieve it from a configuration file.
        //return "Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=true;" +"Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;";
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestData"].ConnectionString;
    }
    private string GetSQL()
    {
        return "Select [Address] From [UserAccount1]";
    }


    void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // have breakpoint here:
        SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;

        // Notices are only a one shot deal
        // so remove the existing one so a new 
        // one can be added

        dependency.OnChange -= OnChange;

        // Fire the event
       /* if (OnNewMessage != null)
        {
            OnNewMessage();
        }*/
    }
```

I have also placed some code in Global.asax file :

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestData"].ConnectionString);
    }
    protected void Application_End()
    {
        // Shut down SignalR Dependencies
        SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestData"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

The SQL server is on local machine. I am running the code through Visual Studio(IIS Express).

1. To enable service broker on database:

   ALTER DATABASE  SET ENABLE_BROKER
      GO
2. To subscribe query notification, we need to give permission to IIS service account

   ```
   GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO “<serviceAccount>”
   ```

I guessed the 2nd point is not needed as it is local. But I tried giving it some permissions. Don't know if they are right as I don't think it is using app pool.And don't need the permission on local env. if I am the user myself and created the schema myself.

One of the questions that I saw was granting :

```
alter authorization on database::<dbName> to [sa];
```

I gave that permission too.

Comment: Can you check two things: 1) that the notification is 'set up', see [`sys.dm_qn_subscriptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/query-notifications-sys-dm-qn-subscriptions) and 2) the notifications messages are not retained in [`sys.transmission_queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-transmission-queue-transact-sql)

Comment: @RemusRusanu I went to views, selected top 1000 rows for `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` and `sys.transmission_queue` . They both were there and they both were empty. Any anomaly ?

Comment: There should be a row in `sys.qn_subscriptions`. I suspect that your query notification is invalidated immediately because it violates one of the restrictions listed [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122(v=sql.105).aspx). You can use a basic `SqlDependency` instead of `SqlCacheDependency` and inpsect what `Info`, `Source` and `Type` value you get in the [`SqlNotificationEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have a row in `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` as soon as I insert something in my table that row in `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` vanishes! so I hope the query notification is not invalidated.. I am now using two part dbName as mentioned in the link you stated.

Comment: In addition to my above comment, as I am doing this for the first time, can you check my OnChange function is correct and should fire up on database change, if there is any additional step required? Because I do see a dependency being created in my application insights.

Comment: I was missing the dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnChange);

Comment: @RemusRusanu, wouldn't have been possible without you.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing :
`dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnChange);`
The new code would look like :

```
               SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

               dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnChange);
```

now I can fire
`void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)`